# Cannot boot dd'ed windows partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, grub, boot-partition, boot-manager

Until yesterday, I was happy with my partition schema:

```
Device         Boot   mounted at    
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *      /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p2        swap
/dev/nvme0n1p3        /             ext4
/dev/nvme0n1p6        /media/Volume ext4
/dev/nvme0n1p5        /home         ext4
```

I also use Windows 10 with virtual box, the vdi is somewhere in /home.

Now I am forced to enlarge the sice of the vdi and, albeit possible, I don't want to have a 100GB vdi file in my /home.
Because I appreciate the idea of being able to boot windows natively and I have > 100GB unparitioned space on my disk, so I

1. created raw img: `VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw Win7.vdi win10.img`
2. analyzed output: `parted win10.img unit B print`

`Number  Start         End           Size          Type     File system  Flags
    1      1048576B      105906175B    104857600B    primary  ntfs         boot
    2      105906176B    54022924799B  53917018624B  primary  ntfs
    3      54023684096B  54522806271B  499122176B    primary  ntfs         diag`

3. created an unformatted partition at `/dev/nvme0n1p7` using gparted
4. copied the second partition from win10.img: `sudo dd if=.local/win10.img of=/dev/nvme0n1p7 skip=105906176 count=53917018624 iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes`

Now if I mount it with `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /media/x`, it complains that windows was not shutdown appropriately and that I shall mount it ro.
I fixed that using`ntfsfix`. It looks like there's a solid windows installation on `/dev/nvme0n1p7`.

Unfortunately, I cannot boot it, neither using virtual box not grub.
For VirtualBox, I created a raw disk using `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename win10.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/nvme0n1 -partitions 7`. After starting the vbox, a black screen appears and that's it.
For grub, I edited `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/nvme0n1p7)" {
 insmod part_msdos
 insmod ntfs
 set root='(hd0,msdos7)'
 chainloader +1
}
```

then I run `sudo update-grub`. It displays `error: not a valid root device`.

I read that grub cannot start windows directly, but only starts a dedicated windows bootloader (chainloader).
I think my problem is that I don't have it.

My Questions: How can I obtain and install that windows bootloader? How can I boot the partition with vbox?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the problem, but reinstalled the whole system (install Windows 10 first, then shrink windows partitions from a live linux and create new partitions for Arch, then install Arch into them).
Using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), I can boot into either Windows or Arch.
From Arch, I can boot the Windows in VirtualBox using [raw disk](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html).

The hardest issues were:

1. What partitions should I use? There is not *the* windows partition. Rather, there are 4:

   - Basic data partition (ntfs, 500MiB)
   - EFI system partition (fat32, 100MiB)
   - Microsoft reserved parition (?, 16MiB)
   - Basic data partition (ntfs, 100GiB)

   Solution: use all 4 (`VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /whatever/you/want.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/nvme0n1 -partitions 1,2,3,4 -relative`). I'm not sure if all are required, but it works.
2. Virtual Box does not boot. Even though it has all information (all partitions mentioned above): Enable efi mode (`Settings` -> `System` -> `Enable EFI (special OSes only)`).
3. Permission issues: Add your user to the `disk`-group: `sudo usermod -a -G disk $USER`.